# How to íterate through an array of sampler2DShadow in GLSL 1.40 (Open GL 3.1)?

Tags: casting, glsl, textures, constants

I want to iterate through an array of sampler2DShadow for a shadow map computation (multiple lights), and it looks like the sampler can be accessed only for a constant index. I only show the relevant code for clarity:

```
smooth in vec4 fShadowTexCoord[5];
uniform sampler2DShadow shadowMapTexSampler[5];

void main() {
     for (uint i = 0u; i < 5u; i++) { // light 'i'
          float shadowCoeff = 0.0f;

          // this line does not work properly
          vec2 scale = 2.0f / textureSize(shadowMapTexSampler[i], 0);

          float bias = 0.006f;
          for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
               for (int k = -1; k <= 1; k++)                
                     shadowCoeff += texture(shadowMapTexSampler[i], vec3(fShadowTexCoord[i].xy + vec2(j, k) * scale, fShadowTexCoord[i].z - bias));

          shadowCoeff /= 9.0f;

          // ...........
     }
}
```

The function 'texture' works as expected, but 'textureSize' function behaves like no texture is bound.
If I replace 'i' with a constant, it works fine, but I didn't found how to cast an 'uint' to a 'const uint' in GLSL.

Comment: "*but 'textureSize' function behaves like no texture is bound.*" What makes you say that? Are you sure it's not a problem with your math? Because that `2.0f` looks dubious.

Comment: The code works well if I remove the 'for' loop and replace 'i' with a compile time constant value.
`const int t = 0; textureSize(shadowMapTexSampler[t], 0); // returns texture size`
 Non-constant array index returns unexpected result:                      
`int t = 0; textureSize(shadowMapTexSampler[t], 0); // returns vec2 (1,1)`

Comment: @NicolBolas, 2.0f is there because the shadow map is rendered in a texture twice the size of screen. What I am trying with that line is to get the screen size, but probably I will send this information via a 'uniform' instead.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the necro post, but this seems to be a limitation of GLSL prior to 4.60 or so?
I do something ugly like this:

```
#define PCF_LOOP(idx) \
else if (faceIdx == idx) \
{ \
    for (int i=0; i<PCF_SAMPLES; i++) \
    { \
        ...
    } \
}

if (false);
PCF_LOOP(0)
PCF_LOOP(1)
PCF_LOOP(2)
PCF_LOOP(3)
PCF_LOOP(4)
PCF_LOOP(5)
```

it's ugly and (probably) slow, but works even on ancient hw